# JVM over CLR and viceversa

Tags: java, .net, jvm, clr

I use Java and .NET since many years now and I see many implementations of the JVM and the CLR around; many OSs, many vendors, etc., but I'm asking here if anyone knows about implementing a CLR on a JVM or a JVM on a CLR.

If such a bridge could be done, it should make thing really more run-time portable!

I know there are few differences and many similarities between CLR and JVM, but there are also cross-compilers between the two runitimes, like XMLVM, and maybe it is possible to give this functionality at runtime...

Is this possible? If not what are the principal technical obstacles?

Comment: Perhaps look at IKVM.NET, which is a JVM-in-CLR bridge. The other way around, one big obstacle might be the *very* different implementation of generics (i.e. the CLR should be able to effortlessly host the type-erased Java generics, but the JVM may struggle with the CLR's type-preserving generics)

Comment: While cross compiling the language is perhaps not hard, you have a problem supporting all the libraries in a native way.  Whatever you come up with has to be better than running Java on a JVM or CLR on mono which is pretty good already.

Comment: Thanks @Marc. Looked at IKVM.NET and found it interesting.

Comment: So, in your opinion @Peter, to have a sort of "run all node" to let any developer to deploy on it, it's better effort to think at a sort of a proxy pattern to choose what runtime to deploy the binaries on instead of a box really capable of running almost anything?

Comment: That might work technically, but there are commercial considerations as well. I don't imagine Oracle and Microsoft producing a joint VM and I don't know of any one with the resources and the *name* to produce a VM which would be more popular than the existing arrangement.

Comment: It is not possible to implement efficiently CLR over JVM. But translating JVM to CLR is relatively trivial, see ikvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) allows to run Java bytecode on top CLR (Mono or MS) and to compile java source code to CLI, of course library support might be an issue.